# Present simple or present continous

Tags: grammar, tenses, syntactic-analysis

Which sentence is correct:

> - I'm eating less chocolate at the moment because I am on a diet.
> - I eat less chocolate at the moment because I am on a diet.

Which tense should be used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We generally use the Present Continuous to talk about what we are doing at present or at a particular time, and the Simple Present to talk about our interests, habits, schedules and the like.

So you would say:

> I am feeding the dog at five o'clock

to indicate that today you will be giving the dog its food at five o'clock.

> I feed the dog at five o'clock

on the other hand means that you usually feed the dog at that hour.

Because in your sentence you speak about *at the moment*, it sounds more natural to say:

> I am eating less chocolate at the moment because I am on a diet.

If you omitted *at the moment*, it would be fair to say:

> I eat less chocolate because I am on diet

suggesting that this is now habitual behaviour and that the diet will last for some time.